# How to cache a model method in django?

Tags: django, django-cache

I have this model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


    def last_post(self):
        if self.post_set.count():
            return self.post_set.order_by("-created")[0]
```

I have noticed that the `last_post` creates a very costly and frequently run query. So I want to cache it for 5 minutes.

I know how to cache a queryset in views but `last_post` bypasses views and is directly called in template. So appreciate your hints on how to cache it.

Comment: Maybe `cached_property` is what you need. Look at: http://www.pydanny.com/cached-property.html

Comment: Sounds good. Can you elaborate it as a complete answer please?

Comment: `@cached_property` will cache the result for the whole request, not for 5 minutes. That perhaps works for you.

Comment: Note that a `cached_property` decorator is now available in Django: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suppose that you can use `cached_property_with_ttl` from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cached-property/1.2.0

```
from cached_property import cached_property_with_ttl

class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @cached_property_with_ttl(ttl=5)
    def last_post(self):
        if self.post_set.count():
            return self.post_set.order_by("-created")[0]
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Great! The only issue is that I'm using 1.8. which does not have `cached_property_with_ttl`. Is there a workaround for that?

Comment: This is not django implementation. It is separate package.

Comment: Well I get this error `from cached_property import cached_property_with_ttl
ImportError: No module named cached_property`. So how should I install/import it in 1.8?

Comment: `pip install cached_property`

Comment: No problems on Windows and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT** : @Yassine Belmamoun pointed out that **this won't work** because the instance dies with the request. I'm keeping it so people have an example of what NOT to do.

### *Original answer* (DO NOT USE):

As @Thomas Druez said, Django now has a built-in [cached_property](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property):

```py
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class Article(models.Model):

    @cached_property
    ## DON'T USE THIS; IT DOES NOT WORK
    ## KEEPING AS REFERENCE OF WHAT NOT TO DO
    def last_post(self):
        if self.post_set.count():
            return self.post_set.order_by("-created")[0]
```

Comment: The `cached_property` decorator "will persist as long as the instance does". This means that the result will be computed for each new request. This won't work.